# Added Page Tab not showing up on Page

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I've gone through all the steps to create a Page Tab in App Settings, such as this...

http://www.dbswebsite.com/blog/2012/10/17/how-to-creating-a-custom-facebook-tab/

I have both the http and https URLs and entered this URL to add the page tab...

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Included my app ID and the website URL. But the Tab is not showing up on our Facebook page. I've clicked the down arrow to show all tabs on the Facebook page and nothing is there. We just have Photos and Likes. The [+] buttons for each blank tab just show a progress bar repeating and repeating. Nothing seems to be working to get this tab to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether your app is in sandbox mode. You can change it in app settings - https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/summary - select the disabled button in Sandbox mode.(sandbox mode is enabled by default)